# Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i make simple application to sending email to my localhost.
in windows 7, my application can run correctly, but when i try to debug and running in windows 8, my application give me some error like this

```
Access to the path 'C:\604ea33a-0b6c-4b47-8e4e-5ff9ff3c35a8.eml' is denied.

 An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

can some one tell me, whats wrong with my code?

thanks

Comment: Are you saving email files to disk? Your application may not have write permission to drive C:, change saving path to some other drive and try..

Comment: yes, i save to my disk.  i'd try to change path to D, or the other. but still error.

Comment: Create a folder in drive D:, give  `Everyone` (user) full permission for the newly created folder. Then change mail saving path to that folder and try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Change my path directory to C:/Windows/Temp 
and run correctly in windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting `UnauthorizedAccessException` .The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

It is clearly a **permission issue**.

In case of `Vista/Windows 7/8`, `C:\` drive is considered as system drive, and  need administrator privileges for your process in order to create files directly under it.

Try running your process with administrator or `Run Visual Studio as Administrator`, and it should work.